# How to setMonth using month names, and displaying a specific day and year

Tags: javascript, date

**Question: How can I use the `new Date();` object to display the full month name, day of the month, and the year with a time stamp?**

```
function displayLastMod()
{
    monthArray = new Array(11);
    monthArray[0] = "January";
    monthArray[1] = "February";
    monthArray[2] = "March";
    monthArray[3] = "April";
    monthArray[4] = "May";
    monthArray[5] = "June";
    monthArray[6] = "July";
    monthArray[7] = "August";
    monthArray[8] = "September";
    monthArray[9] = "October";
    monthArray[10] = "November";
    monthArray[11] = "December";

    var theDate = new Date();
    var theMonth = theDate.setMonth(03);
    var theDay = theDate.setDate(09);
    var theYear = theDate.setYear(2015);

    document.getElementById("lastModified").innerHTML = "Last Modified: " +theDate;
}
```

This code displays `"Last Modified: Thu Apr 09 2015 18:18:37 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)"`

**This is the format I need it in:** `"Last Modified: April 9, 2015 - 6:23:00 PM"`

*Is this possible with only using JavaScript (without other languages or plugins)?*

Comment: Yes is it possible only using [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). And you've got a nice start with the month names in an array `monthArray[theDate.getMonth()]`.

Answer (score 0):

as   much as I know there is no function in javascript print formated date.

Try this:

```
function displayLastMod()
{
    monthArray = new Array(11);
    monthArray[0] = "January";
    monthArray[1] = "February";
    monthArray[2] = "March";
    monthArray[3] = "April";
    monthArray[4] = "May";
    monthArray[5] = "June";
    monthArray[6] = "July";
    monthArray[7] = "August";
    monthArray[8] = "September";
    monthArray[9] = "October";
    monthArray[10] = "November";
    monthArray[11] = "December";

    theDate = new Date();theDate.setHours(16);
    var theMonth = theDate.setMonth(03);
    var theDay = theDate.setDate(09);
    var theYear = theDate.setYear(2015);
    var monthName=monthArray[theDate.getMonth()]
    var day=theDate.getDate();
    var year=theDate.getYear()+1900;
    var hours=theDate.getHours()
    var minutes=theDate.getMinutes();
    var seconds=theDate.getSeconds();

   document.getElementById("lastModified").innerHTML = ("Last Modified: " +monthName+' '+day+', '+year+' - '+hours%12+':'+minutes+':'+seconds+' '+((hours>12)?'PM':'AM'));
}
```